# Visual Studio 2013 Pro installation 0x80070643 error

Tags: visual-studio

When I install Visual Studio Professional with update 4, I get a "package failed" error.

The log file show four errors and one warning.

[image]

The four errors are:

0x80070643: Failed to execute MSU package

0x80070643: Failed to configure pre-machine MSU package

MUX: Set Result: Return Code = -2147023293 (0x80070643) Error Message =, Vital = False, Package Action = Install, Package Id = WindowsIdentityFoundation_x64

Applied non-vital package: WindowsIdentityFoundation_x64, encountered error: 0x80070643.

There was also one warning message:

MUX: Warning : missing display name: WindowsIdentityfoundation_x64

googling led me [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976982/en-us) . I don't know much about .NET etc and I am hoping that I can fix this without opening a whole new can of worms because I am worried that if I tried reinstalling .NET then I may get entangled in a host of other issues.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to apply the Method 1. fix suggested by Microsoft:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976982/en-us

This seems to have fixed the issue for others that I have come across around the web

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it right now. I just needed some reassurance before I embarked on messing with registration and .NET stuff.